# ASP.NET chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am trying to create a column chart in asp.net.  I have a data table which returns value as:

Table   Total   Completed
Table1   10         4
Table2   100        85

I want to show this using column chart like this :-

[image]

can anyone tell me how to use the chart & series of ASP.NET chart control to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stacked barchart control of ajax control toolkit.

```
    <cc1:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server" ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth="450"
        ChartTitle="Your Chart Title" CategoriesAxis="Table 1,Table 2, Table 3, Table 4"
        ChartType="StackedColumn" ChartTitleColor="#0E426C" CategoryAxisLineColor="#D08AD9"
        ValueAxisLineColor="#D08AD9" BaseLineColor="#A156AB">
        <Series>
          <cc1:BarChartSeries Name="DataValues1" BarColor="#6C1E83" Data="4,85,3,11" />
          <cc1:BarChartSeries Name="DataValues2" BarColor="#D08AD9" Data="6,15,18,32" />
        </Series>
    </cc1:BarChart>
```

Comment: I have used this stacked chart, but how to show the percentage in Y-axis, Its only showing the values that i bind to the chart?

Comment: To show percentage on Y axis you have pass the value proportionally ie. Datavalues1 as 40,85.. and Datavalues2 as 60,15.... .Graph shows values on y axis proportional to the values you pass.